# Data Structure for holding quantmod xts object in C#

Tags: c#, r, data-structures, xts, quantmod

I am able to call R from C# successfully. But for the XTS object returned by R, what is a suitable data structure in C#?

R Code is:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", "QQQ")
df <- cbind(Ad(SPY), Ad(QQQ))

> head(df)
           SPY.Adjusted QQQ.Adjusted
2007-01-03     114.3121     39.39500
2007-01-04     114.5547     40.14209
2007-01-05     113.6410     39.95076
2007-01-08     114.1666     39.97810
2007-01-09     114.0695     40.17853
2007-01-10     114.4496     40.65229
```

What I need is a suitable data structure to hold the df XTS object in C#. I tried List of Lists. Array of arrays, but I am looking for an effifient way to hold and iterate through the data in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at `dput(df)` to see the internal data structure. It's basically a matrix, an index vector and some attributes.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I will ckeck it out